# how to make a template always responsive?

Tags: css

As you know everyday new smartphones and tablets are being introduced with different resolutions!
then if I want to make a template based on width, it will fail.
for example, there is an ASUS tablet with 1280px width when landscape, and my laptop is 1280px as well!!! then I cannot use width.

is there any way to responsive a template based on device inch ?

I read [this article](http://mobile.smashingmagazine.com/2013/03/21/responsive-web-design-with-physical-units/) and couldn't figure out how can I match device PPI and device-max-width to get to the device inch if possible..
I need a filter to make my template responsive for ever as I know tablets are always smaller than laptops in inch!

Comment: If you proportionally set values, (i.e. as '%', 'em', 'ex' etc) you should not have to care about how many PPIs the device has.

Comment: when HTC one landscape is 1980px, then what are the proper values for it???!!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use CSS media queries to detect the res of the device being used then apply style per device:

```
/* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 480px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Smartphones (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 321px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Smartphones (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (max-width : 320px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : landscape) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : portrait) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Desktops and laptops ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 1224px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Large screens ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 1824px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPhone 4 ----------- */
@media
only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5),
only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5) {
/* Styles */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use

```
width: 1in;
```

You should be able to get particular inch-based measures. For example:

```
<head>
<style>
.box {
        display: block;
        width: 1in;
        background-color: blue;
}
.bix {
        display: block;
        width: 2in;
        background-color: blue;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<span class='box'>Hi</span>
<span class='bix'>Hi</span>
</body>
```

Will create blue boxes with widths around 1 in and 2 in respectively.

Comment: I have a 11-inch tablet. Im trying to responsive the template for this. so I use `@media only screen (max-width: 11in)` and it doesn't work ! .. consider that I'm talking about Device size in inch

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried @media only screen (max-device-width: 11in)
That should work on Apple and Windows devices, not sure about Android, thought.